# Redirecting URL with a certain parameter in

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I would like to do the follow redirection using htaccess:

> From: http://www.mywebsite.com/home/?page_id=273&mnth=8&yr=1993
>
> To: http://www.mywebsite.com/

However, all of the parameters change quite a lot apart from **page_id**, so if it is possible to redirect all of these pages without having to do one for each possibility, that would be ideal.

Thanks in advance for any help received,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the number of redirects involved, the best answer was to manually redirect each URL using a specific rule for each possibility. Non of the answers supplied helped out unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

I think RedirectMatch only works on the Url-path - ie not the query string.

But can use mod_rewrite

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} page_id=273
RewriteRule home/.* /path/to/new.html [L,R]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also redirect any non existing pages to the home page and let your application handle it from there

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an easy rewrite condition to achieve this, in your **.htaccess**, add:

```
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
RewriteEngine   On

# These are the rewrite conditions
RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_FILENAME}     !-f
RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_FILENAME}     !-d

# And finally, the rewrite rules
RewriteRule ^home/273/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /home/?page_id=273&mnth=$1&yr=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
```

This way you will use the new URL as: `http://www.mywebsite.com/home/273/8/1993`, and it would open `http://www.mywebsite.com/?page_id=273&mnth=8&yr=1993`.

You can also set the 273 dynamically of course.

Comment: I need http://www.mywebsite.com/home/?page_id=273&mnth=8&yr=1993 to open http://www.mywebsite.com/ - so this doesn't work unfortunately

Comment: You have to specify what URL you want **visible** on the address bar, and what file/parameters you actually want executed on the server

Comment: I need to be able to clean up a load of search engine results and redirect them all to the home page, so I can't control or specify what is in the URL

Comment: The you don't want to rewrite URLs, all you need is to redirect with a 302 to the homepage, so that search engines stop indexing those pages.

Comment: Thank you for that, I made it very clear in my question that I needed to redirect and not rewrite. 

"I would like to do the follow redirection using htaccess:"